# Sorting a negative Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

So i want to sort an arrays that contain negative number. I have this in my method. When i run it with negative input , java.lang.negativeArray exception is out. here is the code:

```
protected int size;
protected int offset;

public CountSort2(int nilaiMax,int nilaiMin)
{
   this.size = nilaiMax-nilaiMin+1;
   this.offset=nilaiMin;
}

public void sort(int[] arrInput)
{
    int[] arrFrek = new int[size];
    for(int i=0;i<arrFrek.length;i++)
    {
        arrFrek[i]=0;
    }

    for(int i=0;i<arrInput.length;i++)
    {
        arrFrek[arrInput[i]-offset]+=1;
    }

    for(int i =1; i<arrFrek.length;i++)
    {
        arrFrek[i] = arrFrek[i]+arrFrek[i-1];
    }
    int[] newArrInput = new int[arrInput.length];
    for(int i=0;i<arrInput.length;i++)
    {
        newArrInput[i]=arrInput[i];
    }

    for(int i=0;i<newArrInput.length;i++)
    {
        arrInput[arrFrek[newArrInput[i]-offset]-1]=newArrInput[i];
        arrFrek[newArrInput[i]-offset]-=1;
    }
}
```

did I miss something ?

Comment: The exception is not `NegativeArray` but `NegativeArraySizeException`, whose documentation clearly says `Thrown if an application tries to create an array with negative size`. The stack trace will tell you at what line exactly this happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason is you are passing negative index while creating the array. So consider your statement like:

```
int[] arrFrek = new int[size];
```

Where you defined size as

```
this.size = nilaiMax-nilaiMin+1;
```

So your nilaiMin > nilaiMax and hence you get negative array size exception. You can read about the exception from javadoc [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NegativeArraySizeException.html)

Als note, if say your `arrInput[i]` is 0 and offset is 2, you are trying to access aray with index -2 which is why you will get array index out of bound exception. Note that array index starts from 0 hence it can't be negative.

Comment: No it will throw `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` if index is negative. Try  `int[] arr = new int[4];
  System.out.println(arr[-2]);`

Comment: And then try this :`int[] arr = new int[-4];`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a place in your code which could potentially lead to this exception.

`int[] arrFrek = new int[size];`

From [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NegativeArraySizeException.html)

```
NegativeArraySizeException
Thrown if an application tries to create an array with negative size.
```